# Cppyy map of subclassed or templated objects

Tags: python, c++, std, python-bindings, cppyy

As a follow-up question to [Using cppyy with rvalue pointers and maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469330/using-cppyy-with-rvalue-pointers-and-maps) (Apologies for not coming up with a simpler example)

I am attempted to initialize a `NameToBasisModel(std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Basis<TBasisTemplateType>>>&& nameToBasisMap)` from `cppyy`. I am not sure how to construct an object that takes in a map of `unique_ptrs` of templated, custom classes since `cppyy` seems to treat pointers and objects identically.

In the C++ code, the call looks like this:

```cpp
  // use the PSDs from the output of LALInferenceReadData to fill the FixedNoiseModelComponent
  std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity>>> nameToBasisMap;
  for (const auto& [interferometerName, interferometer] : data_->getInterferometerNameToInterferometerMap()) {

    PowerSpectrumDensity powerSpectrumDensity{interferometer.powerSpectrumDensity.value()};
    const std::string identifier = "fixed noise basis for " + interferometerName;
    auto basis = std::make_unique<FixedBasis<PowerSpectrumDensity>>(identifier, std::move(powerSpectrumDensity),
                                                                    PowerSpectrumDensity{powerSpectrumDensity.getSegmentLengthSec(), powerSpectrumDensity.getSamplingRateHz()});
    nameToBasisMap.emplace(interferometerName, std::move(basis));
  }

  auto noiseModel = std::make_unique<NameToBasisModel<PowerSpectrumDensity>>(std::move(nameToBasisMap));
```

To make my map I first tried:

```py
            # make noise model
            nameToBasisMap = Cpp.std.map[Cpp.std.string, Cpp.Basis[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity]]()
            for interferometerName, interferometer in self.data.getInterferometerNameToInterferometerMap():
                print(interferometerName, interferometer)
                powerSpectrumDensity = Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity(interferometer.powerSpectrumDensity.value())
                identifier = "fixed noise basis for " + interferometerName
                basis = Cpp.FixedBasis[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity](
                    identifier,
                    Cpp.std.move(powerSpectrumDensity),
                    Cpp.std.move(Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity(powerSpectrumDensity.getSegmentLengthSec(),
                                             powerSpectrumDensity.getSamplingRateHz()))
                )
                nameToBasisMap.emplace(interferometerName, Cpp.std.move(basis))
```

However, this failed when making the map (which isn't surprising, Basis itself is not implemented.)

(Here is part of the long traceback, but it is failing when trying to call emplace)

```
  map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >(const std::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >::allocator_type& __a) =>
    TypeError: takes at least 1 arguments (0 given)
  map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >(const std::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >& __m, const std::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >::allocator_type& __a) =>
    TypeError: takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)
  std::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> > constructor failed
  map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >(const std::map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >& __m) =>
    TypeError: takes at least 1 arguments (0 given)
  Failed to instantiate "map<std::string,Basis<PowerSpectrumDensity> >()"
```

I then tried replacing `nameToBasisMap = Cpp.std.map[Cpp.std.string, Cpp.Basis[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity]]()`  with the subclass `nameToBasisMap = Cpp.std.map[Cpp.std.string, Cpp.FixedBasis[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity]]()`

Which creates the map without complaint. However when I try to construct the `NameToBasisModel`

```
noiseModel = Cpp.NameToBasisModel[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity](Cpp.std.move(nameToBasisMap))
```

it segfaults.

I also tried to replace it with

```
nameToBasisMap = Cpp.std.map[Cpp.std.string, Cpp.std.unique_ptr[Cpp.Basis[Cpp.PowerSpectrumDensity]]]()
```

which also crashes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I construct something that explicitly uses pointers in a type?

Comment: "it segfaults" --> [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)